# How to style mat table on hover

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a design for a mat-table. find the attached image. on hover, the row should look like the attached image

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6GUh.png):
[figma image of mat-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6GUh.png)

[table what I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyXer.png)

[stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8gr1n?file=src/app/table/table.component.scss)
[stackblitz link:](https://angular-n8gr1n.stackblitz.io)

```
***Mycode***
**table component.css**

        table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: 'collapse' !important;
        font-family: 'biennale-regular';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color: white;
    }

    tr.mat-row {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        height: 39px !important;
        border-top: 9px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }

    td.mat-cell {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #001C35;
        padding-top: 9px;
        padding-bottom: 9px;
    }

    th.mat-header-cell {
        border-bottom-style: none;
        color: #001C35;
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }

    td.mat-cell:first-child {
        border-left: 2px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
        border-top-left-radius: 13px;
    }

    td.mat-cell:last-child {
        border-right: 2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
        border-top-right-radius: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, it really helps if you can provide a StackBlitz of your issue. That way we can look at your code, and try things, without having to essentially re-create your app.

Second, Angular Material keeps its styles within its components, so you usually wind up needing to use ::ng-deep.

Finally, you have no :hover selector in your CSS.  Assuming you are actually connects with the Material selectors, you'll need something like:

```css
tr.mat-row:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i have added the stack blitz

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't open.  It just spins and spins.