Styling mat-table from Angular Material UI
I need to implement hover effect for the whole row of data (background-color), however, hover works only for the selected mat-cell. Please suggest who to apply hover effect for the whole row (td)

 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td class="table-item" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td class="table-item" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td class="table-item" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td class="table-item" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>


<style>

.table-item:hover {
background: yellow;
}

</style>


Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275638/how-to-style-mat-table-on-hover?rq=2
I often have to use ng-deep to override Material style

You can change the style of tr item  but it will apply it to all rows including header.
tr:hover {
 background: yellow; 
}

A way to apply highlighting to only data row would be by using a class as such
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
    class="table-row"
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  ></tr>

with following css
table tr.table-row:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

Which will change the background on hover to only table tr items with class table-row
Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/w9dtc5?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.css

thanks, it works, but it also applies hover effect for the firsts row(heading), I tried this approach  tr:not(:first-child):hover , to avoid first row selecting, but it does not work

I updated my answer with an alternative, indeed tr:not(:first-child):hover does not seems to work

Super! thanks a lot!
